# copy a file from drive F to all folders in C:\program files

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I've been reading through a lot of stuff on this site and I cannot seem to find an answer to my need.... to the point:

I need to copy 1 file to all folder in `C:\program files` dir, however I'm trying to find a way that I wont need to specify the full path...for a rough example I can

```
REN F:\source\*.bat *.exe
```

(or `.mp3` or `.jpg` or `.vbs` etc etc)

the above commands will rename all `*.bat` files to `*.exe` files, without specifying a path

so I'm looking for a similar command line in a batch to move 1 specific file to multiple folders in a dir without specific paths...

I have tried `%~d0\` and `%programfiles%` but nothing seems to work for me....

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript?

Comment: I haven't used JavaScript much but I know similar command lines can be used in vbscript as in batch files or cmd, some of my research into this as taken me into .JS but I wasn't sure...

Comment: Typically JS  (or VBScript) can't access filesystem or OS, what is the environment here?

Comment: if thats the case a batch file would be the environment, if I'm understanding what you mean by environment correctly

Comment: Because `%ProgramFiles%` is a protected location in modern Windows Operating Systems, you'd need to be able to run this batch file As administrator, _(which is not necessarily the same as having an Administrator account type)_. If you really are crazy enough to want to perform this operation on every directory within that protected location, **you'll need to first confirm that your end user can run this batch script As administrator.**

Comment: What is the use case for doing this? Under my %ProgramFiles% directory there are 17,384 directories. Do you really want to put a file into every directory?

Comment: to clarify, I'm trying to do this because not to long ago my friend was on my laptop and did something to it (downloaded some kind of malicious software I assume) next thing I know i'm looking through my program files, windows, system32, and all sub dir's and all the .dll's/.exe's where changed to a non-usable extension. I ended up having to reformat and lost everything because my external hardrive broke which had my backups on it.... so I was trying to find some way to reverse this damage if it ever happened again. but I do apologize for off-topic/no question at all post

Answer (score 0):

I still do not fully understand the use case for this, but here is something that will copy a file into each subdirectory below the user's "Program Files" directory. Once you are sure that the copies you expect would be done, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Env:ProgramFiles |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path 'C:\src\t t t.txt' -Destination $_.FullName -WhatIf
    }
```

If you must run it from a cmd.exe shell, put the code above into a file named with a .ps1 extension and run:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File copyit.ps1
```

**Notes:**

It is important to use the environment variable `ProgramFiles` because the actual directory name may be in a language you do not know.

There may be permission issues with writing to these directories. Try using `Run as Administrator`.

Yes, there are certainly .bat file script ways to do this. The future Microsoft direction is PowerShell. Might as well start grocking it now.

Comment: see my comment above for explanation on why I'd use this kind of file... I would be using this on my own computer to revser damage done without having to reformate again (which I had to do in this case because my backups were not usable.) I must have misunderstood the point of this site and do apologize!

Comment: I figured out how to run as administrator but still gives me access denied error, code provided with -whatif attached works without error but once removed I get access is denied even with elevated permissions...

Comment: What steps do you take in order to manually copy a file into those directories?

Comment: typically I would make a batch file, xcopy F:\file.exe "C:\program files\Microsoft office" which I guess I could just do in my case since i'm using it for my own pc, I was just hoping for an easier one-click and done type thing.

Comment: Is there any permission problem when you use `XCOPY`?

Comment: no not when I right click and run as administrator, using power shell I was doing the following: 

windows key - powershell - right click - run as administrator - then trying to run code provided with my destination folder so:

 Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Env:ProgramFiles |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path 'F:\file.exe' -Destination $_.FullName    }

Comment: @DesiraeRoberts - Are you saying that the PowerShell code works when you use "Run as Administrator?"

Comment: it doesn't work in powershell even elevated, but xcopy will work elevated is what I was saying.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps someone else has something to add.